# Erlang "system" memory section keeps growing

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, erlang

I have an application with the following pattern:

- 2 long running processes that go into hibernate after some idle time
  and their memory consumption goes down as expected
- N (0 < N < 100) worker processes that do some work and hibernate when idle more than
  10 seconds or terminate if idle more than two hours
- during the night,
  when there is no activity the process memory goes back to almost the
  same value that was at the application start, which is expected as
  all the workers have died.

The issue is that "system" section keeps growing (around 1GB/week).

My question is how can I debug what is stored there or who's allocating memory in that area and is not freeing it.

I've already tested **lists:keysearch/3** and it doesn't seem to leak memory, as that is the only native thing I'm using (no ports, no drivers, no NIFs, no BIFs, nothing). Erlang version is R15B03.

Here is the current **erlang:memory()** output (slight traffic, app started on Feb 03):

```
[{total,378865650},
{processes,100727351},
{processes_used,100489511},
{system,278138299},
{atom,1123505},
{atom_used,1106100},
{binary,4493504},
{code,7960564},
{ets,489944},
{maximum,402598426}]
```

This is a 64-bit system. As you can see, "system" section has ~270MB and "processes" is at around 100MB (that drops down to ~16MB during the night).

Comment: Noticing similar behaviour. I believe it's related to Erlang using generational garbage collection, but I cannot confirm.

Comment: If that is the case, repeated erlang:garbage_collect() or garbage_collect(Pid) on all erlang PIDs should fix it. All it does is to free up some "process_memory", never "system". This is such a common word in IT that makes it impossible to find out some documentation on what kind of data is stored there. Also, by the way, OS reports around 70% more resident memory used.

Comment: can you periodically run memsup:get_memory_data/0? It shows the Pid of and number of allocated bytes of the largest Erlang process on the node. Might provide some insight

Comment: A couple of questions: Will the memory growth continue until it crashes? if you do an explicit GC, does the memory decrease? Is it ONLY the system area the grows?

Comment: GC decreases process_memory section. "system" section is unchanged. Yes, that is the area that always grows and that is what I want to debug somehow. I don't know if it crashes because this is a live machine and app does not afford losing in-flight data. I restart the app every week or so. memsup:get_memory_data() seems to be unavailable as it returs this: (agstats@agentlogin-statistics)3> memsup:get_memory_data().       
{0,0,{<0.20973.2234>,0}}

Comment: Here is the memsup:get_memory_data() result: {16829030400,10289741824,{<0.315.0>,198364928}}. What I understand is that: 16GB total in the system , 10GB used (with buffers/cache). This matches the OS numbers, so it is fine. The largest process at ~200MB looks a little strange, but its current heap is much lower, so it must be a historical value. By the way, current "system" section is at 360MB.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that I've found the issue.

I have a "process_killer" gen_server where processes can subscribe for periodic GC or kill. Its subscribe functions are called on each message received by some processes to postpone the GC/kill (something like re-arm).

This process performs an erlang:monitor if not already monitored to catch a dead process and remove it from watch list. If I comment our the re-subscription line on each handled message, "system" area seems to behave normally. That means it is a bug in my process_killer that does leak monitor refs (remember you can call erlang:monitor multiple times and each call creates a reference).

I was lead to this idea because I've tested a simple module which was calling erlang:monitor in a loop and I have seen ~13 bytes "system" area grow on each call.

The workers themselves were OK because they would die anyway taking their monitors along with them. There is one long running (starts with the app, stops with the app) process that dispatches all the messages to the workers that was calling GC re-arm on each received message, so we're talking about tens of thousands of monitors spawned per hour and never released.

I'm writing this answer here for future reference.

TL;DR; make sure you are not leaking monitor refs on a long running process.